# Invoke another app in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Let consider two apps are working in node js at different ports.

one as app.js(3000) ans other as chat.js(3007).

Now from app.js I want to call chat.js such that chat.js app should update the values that it showing to users.

I tried like this in app.js

```
   var request = require('request');
   request('http://localhost:3007/', function (error, response, body) { 
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

  }
})
```

It doesn't work, chat.js not updating the values it showing to users. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please show us your chat.js code

Comment: This is just HTTP communication, is chat.js receiving the request? Is it sending a response? Is app.js receiving the response?